# Adding aftermarket backup lights

Tags: lights, aftermarket-upgrade

I have a 2011 Ford F-150 Super Cab STX, I find the original backup lights are lacking in lighting up the path I need to drive in reverse, the brake lights do a better job. I already tried replacement LEDs that were touted to be much brighter than the stock 194 bulbs the truck comes with, they were not.

What I want to do as add 2 lights like this [set here](http://www.4wheelparts.com/Lighting-Lighting-Accessories/Optilux-1450-Halogen-Bulb-Fog-Light-Lamp-Kit.aspx?t_c=14&t_s=448&t_pt=4242&t_pn=HLAH71010331&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=shopping&emlprox=out&ppcfon=1&gp=1&gclid=COWXuKXyl8QCFRYdaQodWr0AdQ). If I do, since the other bulbs, the 194 drew only 25 watts each and these proposed lights draw 55 watts each. I believe this will be an issue. Is this the case if I tie them in with the existing back up light circuitry?

I see there are [lights](http://www.autoanything.com/lights/77A3232A2356857.aspx) ready to go in as backup lights, and they are double the cost. The link is just a representation, Ebay has them for less.

So the next question will be, if I use the fog lights, by the time I get the harness so it can handle the load and work off the backup light circuit, would I be better off just getting the ready to install backup light kit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going to use normal fog lights, or other 55w Halogens, you'll need a relay, so you're not drawing the full 10A through the existing circuit. You can find plenty of wiring diagrams on Google, and the parts will only cost you the price of a couple of beers - a relay, a fuse & holder and some wire.

If it were me however, I'd look at the newer LED worklights you can get - CREE ones will be much brighter than cheap aftermarket ones, and will use much less power than 55w Halogens...

Comment: Thanks for answering, I have looked at those, heard they were really bright. They do demand a high price on some of them, and from my experience the one I got from Amazon, http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00O1UHGUM?ref_=pe_823600_114105210 , really let me down. All the reviews I read says these were really good, lumen output was 3X higher than the OEM 194s. It is difficult for me to try LEDs again. If I do, I guess I need to go with the expensive ones, since I don't know how to otherwise gauge what I am needing?

Comment: The thing is, your past experience was with replacement LED bulbs in the stock lamps. I find that combination rarely works as the light output from LEDs is a different pattern from normal incandescent bulbs - LEDs are much more directional. Therefore you need a different shape reflector to get the best out of them, and so they won't work as well in stock lamps, which have a reflector designed for filament bulbs. Complete aftermarket lamps will have a matching reflector, so should be better, if they are done properly...

Comment: I figured the LEDs I had gotten would have worked for sure, between the higher lumens, the way the bulb fit in the housing at an angle so the sides of the bulb would work off the reflector, let alone what would be emitted directly from the exposed sides and tip. I put the truck in reverse in the evening time, set the parking brake and got out to look at them. I was completely disappointed. Nothing directional to look at, no spot light pointed off to the side where the tip of the LED light was pointed at. Big let down. Amazon will give a full refund including shipping and a return label prepaid

Comment: So if you do mind me asking, what route would you take? sounds like the LEDs in the OEM socket is a no-go. I have been a shade tree mechanic since I was 15 years old, worked on all my own cars, until recent, since they were new cars, it didn't need the work except for oil changes and the occasional alternator which I did do. I have added aftermarket radios, repaired wiring harnesses with the same. I have never done anything like this, as in adding relays and something that draws more current that the harness is rated for. I am pretty handy, but I am a little tight with my wallet.

Comment: As it's a pick-up, I'd stick a pair of LED work-lights on the back of the cab. That way, you can use them as worklights when loading and unloading the pickup, and as extra reversing lights when needed. I'd have them on a separate switch on the dash.